# Permission rights for SQL login accessing Database for ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, database-permissions

I always wonder what are the exact access rights and permissions I need to give to a sql login which I use from my asp.net application to access database. The application execute some stored procedures which insert, update and delete data into tables. I do select, delete, update directly on the tables also. Also there are some triggers. 
Wonder if there is a comprehensive list of the permission matrix to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends on how complicated you want to make it :-)

**Simplest solution:**

- make your login / db user have the db_datareader role to read all tables
- make your login / db user have the db_datawriter role to write all tables

As for executing stored procs, what we did is create a new custom database role "db_executor" in our database like this:

```
CREATE ROLE [db_executor] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GRANT EXECUTE TO [db_executor]
```

and then we grant this role to the db user as well. This new custom database role will have execute rights on all existing *AND* on all future stored procs/funcs in your database.

With this, your db user can read and write any table and execute any stored proc and stored func.

**More complex solution:**
You can of course also GRANT permissions on individual tables, views, procs, funcs to inidividual db users and/or db roles. But it can get quite messy and complicated.

Marc